# How to enable zoom in/out in IBM MobileFirst hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, zooming, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a simple MobileFirst hybrid app with only html, js, no native call. When install and run the app on iOS and Android, pages are not zoom-able. If run it in mobile browser like preview, pages are zoom-able. The viewport meta tag in the html head section is set as "`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">`". Is there any other configuration need to be set to make the app zoom-able?

Answer (score 1):

That's because while the app is created using HTML, etc... it's still an *app* - not a web page, and so makes it sense that it will not be zoomable. You don't want your app to feel like a webpage, but like an app.

For example, you can review Apple's page on Do and Don't when creating an application: https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/

Your application's design should be with the mindset of an app - fitting the screen, not dense, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would like the whole page be zoomable for all environment, not just a specific area. Is there any api to globally set it?

Comment: @JenniferHu, What is the purpose of pinch & zoom in your app?

Comment: I guess for accessibility reason. For example, we have lot of forms, it is easier to enter data when zooming.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I disagree, how would zooming help here? you are supposed to develop your application in a manner that befits a mobile app, not as a webpage. Zooming is absolutely the WRONG solution. Even if there are a lot of buttons - you're supposed to design the UI of your app and not cramp them all together... you are thinking in the wrong way about app devleopment.

Comment: I do see lot of mobile apps are zoomable, and we want our app be zoomable too. If making the whole page zoomble is not possible, we would like to make some field zoomable, e.g. an input field in html. How do we do that?

Comment: See here for design tips (how mobile apps should act): https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/

Comment: In other words, you need to design bigger and have the design fit. If you have an input field - make it bigger. It's not a matter of zooming. It's a matter of designing the app. An input field's size can be made bigger using JavaScript. also dynamically.